# Change Name of Bluetooth Device (Magic Mouse) in macOS Catalina?

Tags: bluetooth, macos-catalina, magic-mouse

I am having trouble to change the name of my Apple's Magic Mouse (older model) on MBP.

I did my research and looked in to all the options of debugging to reset the BT module but nothing worked. I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.3 and I am wondering is it the Catalina?

Does anyone know how to change the name of a connected bluetooth device on macOS?

Comment: Are you looking for Swift code to do so?

Comment: @Codo tbh I can try that as well, it is just bugging me as it should be simple in theory but I am not able to do it so I can try Swift code as well.